# How do I populate tags for C?

Tags: c, ctags, tags

I hover over stdlib:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I type `M-.` and it asks me:

```
Visit tags table (default TAGS):
```

I don't have one of those.  I see a lot of information about TAGS in the emacs documentation:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TagsFile#tags_file

But what should I use, CTAGS, ETAGS, Universal CTags, Global Tags?  Should I set this up in the makefile or in a key binding?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `etags` because it comes with Emacs and is what the default implementation of `M-.` targets.

Given a C project you can use `etags *.c *.h` to generate the `TAGS` file in that directory and select it when prompted by `M-.`. Some C projects already provide a `Makefile` target for that, for example you can run `make tags` in the Emacs sources to generate them for the Lisp and C parts. This is highly useful to jump to the source of a definition.

Comment: Is this something people generally do "out of band" from having a file up in the editor---done calling etags in the makefile via an external shell, versus having an emacs macro for running this process?

Comment: Matter of taste really. For the Emacs sources it's not worth it for me to automate the task because I just use them to find out where a built-in is defined and only update them after each stable Emacs release. Do whatever works for you.

Comment: Yes, most projects add a `tags` target to their Makefile, and make it a dependency of the `all` target. That way they can regenerate the TAGS file whenever they recompile, such as with `M-x compile`.